# How to change the Theme of an activity after it is created?

Tags: android, android-theme

After creating an activity, how can I change its theme to a new one, for example, `Theme.Holo`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the theme of an Activity after it is created. You can change the theme before any Views are added, but not after.

As per [the docs for `setTheme(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29):

> Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).

If you wish to change the theme *before* any Views are added, you can do so in `onCreate()` like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(myThemeResourceId);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: is the Theme will e available as resourceID? how to know the ID of,e.g" theme.holo?

Comment: Yes- `android.R.style.Theme_Holo`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
    activity.setTheme(yourThemeID);
    super.onCreate(bundle);
}
```

Comment: is the Theme will e available as resourceID? how to know the ID of,e.g" theme.holo?

Comment: @Elpharaoh use `android.R.style.Theme_Holo`.